# How to read multiple CSV files from Google in Jyputer Notebook and traverse each file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, google-drive-shared-drive

I have 45 files in my Google Shared Drive. I need to load them in Jyputer Notebook. Each files are data for each month for the last 3 years.

I need result for each file. How do I do this Pandas?

The operations are as follows:

1. Read all 45 files
2. Get Sum(col 1), Sum(col 2), Sum(Col 3) for each file
3. Get Sum(col 1), Sum(col 2), Sum(Col 3) grouped by Col X

Code i found:

```
import pandas as pd

url='https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/ABC'
file_id=url.split('/')[-2]
dwn_url='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + file_id
df = pd.read_csv(dwn_url)
print(df.head())
```

its throwing 404 error

Answer (score 0):

404 is HTTP authentication error, you can try two ways:

1. Use [Google python package](https://pypi.org/project/gcloud/) to authenticate and download the files locally first, then open with pandas. -- recommended way.
2. Use [a signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). Note, this hard-coded url if known by others, they can also access your file. So it seems easier but often is not safe.

Comment: I tried by installing google.colab. Now my entire Jpyuter Notebook is crashed and i'm unale to launch it